Unable to perform handshake with Salesforce using .NET Core CometD - can anyone provide working code?
I am trying to connect to a Salesforce channel using CometD in a .NET Core application, but I am unable to perform the handshake with the server. I'm using the following code to establish the connection, but the handshake fails.
Here is my code:
using CometD.NetCore.Bayeux.Client;
using CometD.NetCore.Client;
using CometD.NetCore.Client.Transport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

public class SalesforceBayeuxClient
{
    private readonly string _accessToken;
    private readonly string _instanceUrl;
    private BayeuxClient _bayeuxClient;

    public SalesforceBayeuxClient(string accessToken, string instanceUrl)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        _instanceUrl = instanceUrl;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        var options = new Dictionary<String, Object>
                {
                    { ClientTransport.TimeoutOption, 120 * 1000 }
                };

        var transport = new LongPollingTransport(options);

        var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
       
        headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
        transport.HeaderCollection = headers;
        
        // Initialize BayeuxClient with the Salesforce CometD endpoint
        _bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient($"{_instanceUrl}/cometd/62.0", new[] { transport });

        // Perform the handshake
        _bayeuxClient.Handshake();

        // Verify connection
        if (_bayeuxClient.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Salesforce.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect to Salesforce.");
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(string channel, Action<IDictionary<string, object>> messageHandler)
    {
        _bayeuxClient.GetChannel(channel).Subscribe(new Listener());
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _bayeuxClient.Disconnect();
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from Salesforce.");
    }
}

